# .nc file flipped and rotated in qgis, no CRS, need to be able to project properly to make a masl

Tags: raster, attribute-table, merge, netcdf, combine

[image]I have two separate files, one is my Land Surface Temperature and the other is the Grid with the lat/lon both are .nc
I wanted to add my grid, which comes in as an attribute table, to my Land Surface Temperature.

Is there a way to merge/join/combine them?

Comment: so the Land Surface Temperature has no grid info? but is in .nv? i'm a bit confused

Comment: That is my confusion as well. I can get the image to load and show my my LST data. However, loading my .shp file so I can work on creating a mask they are not on top of one another. What am I missing or not doing that is causing my .nc file to do this?

Comment: oh, so the LST .nc does plot as expected? as in it has spatial properties? check the dims of the LST.nc, what are the names of the dim attributes and what are their values like? is there are CRS in the global attributes?

Comment: What software are you using?   I often use `ncks` from the NetCDF Operators ( http://nco.sourceforge.net/ ) to append compatible-dimensioned .nc files together into combined .nc files.

Comment: I am using both matlab and qgis, my goal is to make a mask over NYC. Why is happening is when I open my LST.nc in qgis it is upside down and rotated, there is no CRS and even when assigned manually there is no recognizable lat/lon. 
Layer Spatial Reference System provided is this "+proj=geos +lon_0=-89.5 +h=35786024 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752.314706705 +units=m +no_defs +sweep=x". The gridded information is in a separate .nc

How can I apply my lat/lon from my separate grid.nc and bring it onto my LST.nc so I can be able to make the mask.

I appreciate the help!